# Share URL to Messages with Rich Preview in Swift

Tags: swift, uiactivityviewcontroller

When I share a webpage (example: apple.com) from Safari to the Messages app, it shares a rich preview in a custom UI element with an image and the page's title and URL.

However, when I try to share a URL to Messages from my own code (even if it's one that works from Safari like apple.com), it just shares the URL as plain text. How can I get the same behavior as Safari when link sharing to Messages?

Here is my code that creates and presents the `UIActivityViewController` that shares the URL:

```
extension UIViewController {
    func shareUrl(url: URL) {
        let objectsToShare: Array<NSObject> = [url as NSObject]

        let activityVC = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: objectsToShare,
                                                  applicationActivities: nil)

        present(activityVC, animated: true)
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi! Did you manage to find a way to share the same preview image as Safari does with your share extension?

Answer (score 0):

```
let items = [URL(string: "https://www.apple.com")!]
let ac = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: items, applicationActivities: nil)
present(ac, animated: true)
```

More detail please see at [here](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/articles/118/uiactivityviewcontroller-by-example)

Comment: That's literally the exact same thing as what I posted in the question... Did you actually test this to see if it does what I'm asking for?

Comment: @kmell96 This is different, activityItems is array include URL object, and you cast to NSObject